# Move Ai brushes to Ps?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

My son wants to move his brushes from Ai to Photoshop.  We just got through reading on this site how to move his color using the exchange but I am not seeing a similar way to do it with brushes.

Answer (score 1):

Brushes are **not** directly transferable between Photoshop and Illustrator or vice versa. You can copy/paste them as artwork, but you can't transfer them as "live" brushes the same way you can color swatches.